# Chained Conditions that require order to not produce order

Tags: python, conditional-statements, keyerror

Whenever I **chain conditions** in Python (or any other language tbh) I stumble upon asking myself this, kicking me out of the productive "Zone". 
When I chain conditions I can, by ordering them correctly, check conditions that without checking for the other conditions first, may produce an Error.

As an example lets assume the following snippet:

```py
if "attr" in some_dictionary and some_value in some_dictionary["attr"]:
    print("whooohooo")
```

If the first condition wasnt in the first place or even absent, the second condition my produce an `KeyError`

I do this pretty often to simply save space in the code, but I always wondered, if this is good style, if it comes with a risk or if its simply "pythonic".

Comment: Why not `if some_value in some_dictionary.get(attr, []):`? Then you only have one condition, and it's safe from `KeyError`s.

Comment: Sure this applies for this specific example but I am asking in a more general context of any conditions

Comment: Well isn't that rather broad? In any possible condition, the answer is to do what makes sense in that condition. In this case it makes sense to either use `dict.get` to avoid the `KeyError` if it's expected that the key will sometimes be missing, or allow the exception to propagate to the caller if it's unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

A more Pythonic way is to "ask for forgivness rather than permission". In other words, use a try-except block:

```
try:
    if some_value in some_dictionary["attr"]:
        print("Woohoo")
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is a late binding language, which is reflected in these kind of checks. The behavior is called [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). One thing I often do is:

```
def do(condition_check=None):
    if condition_check is not None and condition_check():
        # do stuff
```

Now, many people will argue that `try: except:` is more appropriate. This really depends on the use case!

- `if` expressions are faster when the check is likely to fail, so use them when you know what is happening.
- `try` expressions are faster when the check is likely to succeed, so use them to safeguard against exceptional circumstances.
- `if` is explicit, so you know precisely what you are checking. Use it if you know what is happening, i.e. strongly typed situations.
- `try` is implicit, so you only have to care about the outcome of a call. Use it when you don't care about the details, i.e. in weakly typed situations.
- `if` works in a well-defined scope - namely right where you are performing the check. Use it for nested relations, where you want to check the top-most one.
- `try` works on the entire contained call stack - an exception may be thrown several function calls deeper. Use it for flat or well-defined calls.

Basically, `if` is a precision tool, while `try` is a hammer - sometimes you need precision, and sometimes you just have nails.